# How can I export a react material-ui component with

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I would like to export a styled text link component using `react` and `material-ui` and `withStyles`, but my code returns:

> Acorn error: Shorthand property assignments are valid only in
>   destructuring patterns (14:9)

With the breakpoint on line 14

```
12  exports.default = styles_1.withStyles({
13      text,
14      type = "", // Error happens here
15      align = "",
16      className = "",
17      to = "",
18  })(styles);
```

---

Code referring to TextLink component:

```
import TextLink from '../components/TextLink'

<div>
    <TextLink to="/sign-up" type="body1" align="center" className="testing" text="Sign up" />
</div>
```

Textlink component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const styles = {
  testing: {
    color: 'green'
  },
};

export default withStyles({
  text, 
  type = "",
  align = "",
  className = "",
  to = "",
})(styles) =>
  <Typography 
    type={`${type}`} 
    align={`${align}`}> 
      <Link
        to={`${to}`}
        className={`${className}`}
      > 
        {text}
      </Link>
  </Typography>;
```

Edit: As response to Timo's answer. The textlink component works fine without withstyles like this:

```
export default ({
  text, 
  type = "",
  align = "",
  className = "",
  to = ""
}) =>
  <Typography 
    type={`${type}`} 
    align={`${align}`}> 
      <Link
        to={`${to}`}
        className={`${className}`}
      > 
        {text}
      </Link>
  </Typography>;
```

Comment: You're passing an object to withStyles, so what are you expecting the equal sign to do?

Answer (score 2):

This is simply not how you define an object in JS.

Use colons to separate the keys from the values:

```
exports.default = styles_1.withStyles({
    text,
    type: "",
    align: "",
    className: "",
    to: ""
})(styles);
```

Comment: As far as I understand, this error shows that the code compiles incorrectly because without withstyles the component works fine (See my updated question). So it must be because I use withStyles incorrectly I assume.

Comment: Pretty much, since creating an object the way you are trying to is a syntax error.

Comment: Ok I got my inspiration from this loader button component: https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/give-feedback-while-logging-in.html#create-a-loader-button. That loaderbutton works fine and also my code works fine without using withStyles. I just can't figure out how to include styles inside the exported component...

Comment: In this case, they define an arrow function and use destructuring and default values for the arguments. Entirely different situation. :-)

Comment: The code without withstyles also uses an arrow function and destructuring, identical to that example. For that reason that code actually works without errors. Assuming you are indeed right that this function is syntactically wrong, can you explain me why that code works fine then?